# Find average number of views before first lead event happens

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
create table events (
fk_user integer,
event varchar(40),
time integer
);


Insert into events (fk_user, event, time)
VALUES
('1', 'view', '1'),
('1', 'view', '3'),
('1', 'view', '4'),
('1', 'lead', '5'),
('1', 'view', '6'),
('1', 'view', '7'),
('1', 'lead', '9'),
('2', 'view', '1'),
('2', 'lead', '2'),
('2', 'lead', '3'),
('2', 'view', '6'),
('2', 'view', '7'),
('2', 'view', '8'),
('5', 'view', '1'),
('5', 'view', '2'),
('2', 'view', '4'),
('2', 'lead', '5'),
('2', 'view', '9');
```

What I am trying to find is: There are 3 'views' before a 'lead' occurs from the top. I want to take the average of the 'time' of first three occurrences. Is it possible to do with the window function ?
Expected output should be: (1+3+4)/3 = 2.666 (If taken integer then 3)

Comment: do you have to do it for every occurrence of lead?

Comment: No just for the first lead

Comment: and for every user? and which column specifies the ordering?

Comment: No for the first one only, consider the structure as ordered

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `min` window function along with a `case` statement to find the `first_lead_time` per `fkuser` and then use a derived table to get the average value of the `views` rows that become before the `first_lead_time`

```
select fkuser, avg(time) from (
    select * , 
        min (case when event = 'lead' then time end) over (partition by fkuser) as first_lead_time
    from events
) t where time < first_lead_time
and event = 'view'
group by fkuser
```

Another way

```
select e.fk_user, avg(e.time)
from events e
join (
    select min(time) first_lead_time, fkuser
    from events
    where event = 'lead'
    group by fkuser
) t on t.fkuser = e.fkuser
where e.time < t.first_lead_time
group by e.fkuser
```